# bc seems to be slow when calculating floating point

Tags: floating-point, bc

After moving from integer values to floating point values in my code I got VERY bad performance.

I am using bc in this way:

```
stat=$(bc -l <<< "$curr < $txBndMax") 
buf=$(echo " $rx2Summ + $rx2SummBuf" | bc)
```

Does the way I`m using bc is wrong? Or in bash I can calculate and compare values with floating point in another way?

Thx for your comments. 
Actually I am parsing variable of 150 000 - 900 000 values in cycle from memory. for each line I make comparation. Script lenght is 300+ lines but basic state machine looks like this pseudo code:

```
read value
case $value in
state1)
        comparation
        calculation
state2)
        comparation
        calculation
...

state8)
        comparation
        calculation
```

Comment: You are calling external program to perform an arithmetical operation. That would be hardly ever performant. If you need arithmetics, then you are strongly advised to switch to Perl/Python/Ruby/etc. Or at the very least, use the languages for the "performance-critical" part of your bash script.

Comment: Completely agreed with @Dummy00001 - maybe you should reformulate your question to show a bit more context and make it clear which parts of your script must be run in the shell, then we would be in a better position to help you. There's nothing wrong with the way you're calling `bc`, it's just that launching a new process to do a single calculation is very inefficient.

Comment: it would help if you did a `time` on the commands, and told use what you are getting, and gave us some sample values of what your variables are set at.  Also, are you sure this is the second of your code that hangs?  I'm getting great response time.

Comment: I updated topic with the structure of the program and a bit of explanation. Variables take values like 816.0428